# what's the difference of two functions in Scala?

Tags: scala

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(test(1, fun1)) // result is 1
    println(test(1, fun2)) // result is 1, too
  }

  def test(i: Int, fun: Int => Int) = fun(i)

  // function fun1
  def fun1(i: Int) = i
  // function fun2
  def fun2 = (i: Int) => i
}
```

The two functions pass to `test` function, and output the same result.

what's the difference of `fun1` and `fun2`?

Answer (score 4):

In Scala terminology your code is expressing two *methods*. If we analyze the code *semantically*, the two methods will yield the same output for any given input. Meaning, for any two equal *domains*, these methods will produce the same *range* of values.

If we look at them from the *compilers* perspective, the two differ with the fact that the former takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`, while the latter takes no arguments and returns a *function* of type `Function1[Int, Int]`, which itself takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`. Logically, you can think of it as a `Function0[Function1[Int, Int]]` (you can see it if you call `fun2 _` in the REPL), but in reality it's simply the invocation of `fun2`.

In order for the former to compile, the compiler performs *eta-expansion*, turning the *method* into a *function*. We can see this with a little flag to `scalac`:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  scala.this.Predef.println(scala.Int.box(App.this.test(1, {
    {
      (new <$anon: Function1>(): Function1)
    }
  })));
  scala.this.Predef.println(scala.Int.box(App.this.test(1, App.this.fun2())))
};
```

And we can also see the auto generated class created for the former to be turned into an actual `Function1[Int, Int]` object:

```
@SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class $anonfun$fun2$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp with Serializable {
  def <init>(): <$anon: Function1> = {
    $anonfun$fun2$1.super.<init>();
    ()
  };
  final def apply(i: Int): Int = $anonfun$fun2$1.this.apply$mcII$sp(i);
  <specialized> def apply$mcII$sp(i: Int): Int = i;
  final <bridge> <artifact> def apply(v1: Object): Object = scala.Int.box($anonfun$fun2$1.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)))
}
```

Comment: Thus the reference to `fun2` is a method call, whereas the reference to `fun1` is a simple name access.

Comment: @Elazar Not sure what you mean by "simply name access". The call to `fun2` is a simple invocation of a `Function0[Function1[Int, Int]]`, where the call to `fun1` has to be expanded to create a concrete class instance. There is a definite distinction between the two.

Comment: You simply refer to the name of the method. Just  like referring to any other variable.

Comment: @Elazar In order to "just refer" to the name of the method, the compiler has to do some trickery based on the evaluation of the named method.

Comment: The fact that something is "expanded to create a concrete class instance" is an implementation detail.

Comment: I don't care what the compiler has to do. That is its own business.

Comment: @Elazar I'd argue that a named method which takes no arguments and generates a function isn't semantically identical to a method taking an argument and returning it, but that's just me. I'm assuming the OP *does* care how the two differ.

Comment: I agree with you argument, and it has nothing to do with the compiler.

Comment: In other words, to claim that they differ you need to show different behavior. I think it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Elazar What do you mean by "behavior"? How is a behavior of a function defined? What criteria would qualify one is different than the other in terms of their behavior?

Comment: You can show two programs, one with fun1 and one with fun2 (and otherwise identical) that have different externally visible behavior, e.g. different output. That's what the OP trying to do.

Comment: As your code snippet shows `fun2` is not going to be eta-converted to `Function0[Function1[Int, Int]]`. When you use `fun2` as a parameter in `test` Scala will simply evaluate it, i.e. call _method_ `fun2` which return type is what it needs.

Comment: @VictorMoroz Definitely. I revised the wording to express what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happens in a nutshell:

```
println(test(1, fun1)) // result is 1
```

->

```
// fun1 is a method which takes one argument,
// but we are using it without arguments, so
// it must be a partial application
// and test expects a function,
// so let's convert it to a function 
val res0 = (x: Int) => fun1(x)
val res1 = test(1, res0)
println(res1)
```

vs

```
println(test(1, fun2)) // result is 1, too
```

->

```
// fun2 takes no arguments, so it's a valid call
// and its return type is consistent with test expectations
val res0 = fun2() // () are optional in Scala 
val res1 = test(1, res0)
println(res1)
```

**UPDATE**

You can explicitly convert a method to a function by using `_`:

```
scala> fun1 _
res0: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1435/1367214620@3db13b89
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how they are different - I have added type annotations to make things clear and placate the compiler.

Given:

```
trait T {
  def fun(i: Int) : Int
}
```

The first definition compiles:

```
object A extends T {
  // fun1 equivalent
  override def fun(i: Int) : Int = i
}
```

But the second does not:

```
//error: object creation impossible,
//since method fun in trait T of type (i: Int)Int is not defined
object B extends T {
  // fun2 equivalent
  // error: method fun overrides nothing.
  override def fun : Int => Int = (i: Int) => i
}
```

For details see the other answers.

Comment: I'm not sure what this example is trying to show? *Semantically* identical does not mean *syntactically* identical, as I've explained what I mean by that in my answer. If your answer is supposed to show the OP these methods are syntactically identical, I think he knows that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov These definitions are not equivalent. "syntactically identical" means "same program text", which of course isn't the case here. Semantically, the first declaration overrides the trait's declaration, and the other does not.

Comment: What the OP want's to know is whether it ever matters, which one will be defined. The answer is "yes", and it exemplified here.

Comment: Your answer about semantic equivalence refers to the behavior of the defined function. My answer (and the op's question) refers to the definition itself. *semantically*, not syntactically.

Comment: How exactly do you know that when the OP said *"what's the difference of fun1 and fun2"* he meant the "definition of the method"? Seems like a pretty wide question to me that leaves plenty of room for interpretation. But if you're so confident that's what he meant, I'm sure he can verify that.

Comment: My answer attempts to tackle both the semantic behavior of both methods, and the compilers interpretation, nothing more. If you think this answer sheds a different light on the OP's question, great, then the OP gained another answer from a different perspective.

Comment: I'm guessing, of course. Based on the test trying to use higher-order function looking for different behavior. I did upvote your answer since it covers important angles.